# SQL_Case and When

Tags: sql, case, feature-selection

I have a data set where I need to calculate minimum amount due. I have used the below code

```
SELECT *, Sales - Reversal AS Net_Sale, charge1 - charge1_rev AS Net_Fee1,

CASE WHEN Net_Sale < 500 THEN Net_Sale
ELSE 0.1*Net_Sale END 
AS Min_Sale_amt,

Min_Sale_amt + Net_Fee1 AS Min_AmountDue
FROM Table
```

The intention is to bring minimum amount due as Rs. 500 if the net sales is less than Rs. 500, if the net sales is more than Rs. 500 then I need to calculate 10% of Net sales.

Sample data for reference

```
create table sales(
sales int,
Reversal int,
charge1 int,
charge1_rev int
);

Insert into sales values(1000,200,10,0);
Insert into sales values(495,0,10,0);
```

For some reason I'm unable to get the result.
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the aliases in a CTE first, then subquery that to get the result you want:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, Sales - Reversal AS Net_Sale,
              charge1 - charge1_rev AS Net_Fee1,
              CASE WHEN Sales - Reversal < 500
                   THEN Sales - Reversal
                   ELSE 0.1*(Sales - Reversal) END AS Min_Sale_amt
    FROM sales
)

SELECT *, Min_Sale_amt + Net_Fee1 AS Min_AmountDue
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Just a comment, according to ANSI SQL, a single `*` in the select list may not be combined with anything else. To be standard compliant, do `select cte.*, ...`. (Some dbms's are picky here...)

Comment: @jarlh Correct, and for Oracle, my query would not compile.  But for most databases, it is OK.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I tried to run the above query which worked. However I wont be able to run temp tables on the servers. Any inputs for a work around would help a lot!